# URL dinâmica no laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de sites para escritores. Nesse projeto existem 12 gêneros dentro da tabela "categorias", por exemplo: Poemas, Acrósticos, Crônicas, etc.

Estou com problemas para criar as rotas para os gêneros corretamente. Vamos supor que um usuário publique um texto do gênero Acrósticos com título: Flores do campo.

A URL está sendo gerada assim: site.com/Acrósticos/flores-do-campo/

Mas eu nao quero que as categorias venham com letra maiscula e acentos na url, fora em outras partes do site. Sendo assim, qual melhor método pra resolver essa situação ?

Criar 12 rotas para cada categoria e puxar apenas o slug do titulo dinamicamente ? ou remover os acentos e letras maisculas na hora de gerar a URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Saudações

Minha sugestão nesse caso é remover os acentos e letras maiúsculas  e gerar o slug manualmente. Eu sempre digo que dinâmico é melhor que estático, vai te dar menos trabalho de manutenção no futuro.

Aqui tem uma função para isso:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955251/php-function-to-make-slug-url-string

Comment: eu resolvi deuma outra maneira. Criei uma coluna slug para as categorias

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o ideal é você trabalhar com `slug`, essa [biblioteca](https://github.com/cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable#installation) pode ajudar bastante com isso, ela gera `slugs`a partir de qualquer campo que você configurar e ela ainda faz o tratamento para o `slug`ser único.